# Dynamics CRM 2011 Search using REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, full-text-search, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to do a keyword search in Java Script using REST API calls in MS Dynamics CRM.

IS it possible to do cause i see only create, update, retrieve and delete REST endpoints.

Please pour your thoughts, how it can be implemented in Javascript and if not in Javascript then how?

And is there a LIKE query option or a similar functionality keyword, which can be used as a filter in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already tried ODATA Query Designer. I dont have a LIKE query option. So what i did was, I used the **substring** query option to make the search which is the maximum i can get from ODATA for search.

```
https://xxx.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ArticleSet
/$filter=substringof('<searchString>','<entity property>')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to build your query using the ODATA Query Designer: http://crm2011odatatool.codeplex.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

MS Dynamics CRM supports [Open Data Protocol](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions)
Here described how to use it inside CRM [OData System Query Options Using the REST Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx)
Also you can see at function

```
 retrieveMultipleRecords: function (type, options, successCallback, errorCallback, OnComplete) {
```

in this sample [Sample: Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete Using the REST Endpoint with JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx)

Comment: Thanks pal. Already saw that. I need to make search using the like keyword. And all is available is the substring in the query options. Probably will have to use it i guess.